# Can't retrieve an email from a webpage using the requests module

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to fetch an email from a [webpage](https://global-standard.org/find-suppliers-shops-and-inputs/certified-suppliers/database/search_result/38996) using requests module. The problem is, the email address seems to be encoded or something, which is why it is unreadable, and I wish to decode it in its usual form.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://global-standard.org/find-suppliers-shops-and-inputs/certified-suppliers/database/search_result/38996'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

res = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
email = soup.select_one("script[type='text/javascript']:-soup-contains('emailProtector')").contents[0]
print(email)
```

When I run the above script, the following is what I get:

```
emailProtector.addCloakedMailto("ep_586c4771", 1);
```

This is the result I'm after:

```
fttextilegroup2017@gmail.com
```

Comment: `{'href': 'javascript:/* This email address is being protected from spambots.*/'}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```py
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://global-standard.org/find-suppliers-shops-and-inputs/certified-suppliers/database/search_result/38996'

def decloak(cloaked_tag, attr_name):
    a, b = "" , ""
    for span in cloaked_tag.select('span'):
        for attr in span.attrs:
            if attr == attr_name:
                a += span[attr]
            else:
                b = span[attr] + b
    return a + b

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
attr_name = re.search(r'nodeName\.toLowerCase\(\)\.indexOf\("(.*?)"', str(soup)).group(1)
mail = decloak(soup.select_one('.cloaked_email'), attr_name)
print(mail)
```

Prints:

```
fttextilegroup2017@gmail.com
```